# How can i have Variable in middle of url in php which is pointing to a api?

Tags: php, api, curl

i want to add a $var[5]which is containing string value to the {subscription_reference} part of the following url.

```
$url5 = $api_entry_point ."/subscription/{subscription_reference}/credentials";
```

it needs to be like this..

```
$url5 = $api_entry_point ."/subscription/0997f4ea6b6ca709/credentials";
```

I have tried different ways but all gone wrong.here are those

```
$url5 = $api_entry_point ."/subscription/'.$var[5].'/credentials";

$url5 = $api_entry_point ."/subscription/$var[5]/credentials";
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this :

```
$url5 = $api_entry_point."/subscription/".$var[5]."/credentials";
```

Comment: this is a very simple string operation... are you sure you have the required data in `$var[5]` ?

Comment: If $var[5] contains "0997f4ea6b6ca709", this should work. In your example you mix " and '

Answer (score 2):

The long way:

```
$url5 = $api_entry_point ."/subscription/".$var[5]."/credentials";
```

or

```
$url5 = $api_entry_point .'/subscription/'.$var[5].'/credentials';
```

They both work the same. But you need to use either `"`or `'`. Don't mix them.

The fanzy way:

```
$url5 = $api_entry_point ."/subscription/{$var[5]}/credentials";
```

This onyl works witht he `"`. They check if anything in the string is a variable. So a normal `"asd $var asd"`would understand `$var` as a variable. But this won't work with special signs like `[] or ()` and so on. Thus you have to put the variable in the `{}` for the string to know which parts a pieces of variables.

Answer (score 2):

You were pretty close, but got tangled up with your quotes ;-)

```
$url5 = $api_entry_point ."/subscription/'.$var[5].'/credentials";
```

Should be...

```
$url5 = $api_entry_point ."/subscription/" . $var[5] . "/credentials";
```

or you could have used:

```
$url5 = $api_entry_point ."/subscription/{$var[5]}/credentials";
```